# how to tell which key is duplicated when mulitple unique keys are configured

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema defined as below:

```
var UserSchema = [{
    id: {               // unique id for users, store as int
        type: Number, index: true, unique: true },
    login: {            // login name
        type: String, index: true, unique: true },
    mail: {             // mail address
        type: String, index: true, unique: true }
}, {
    id: false           // disable mongoose's automatic id mapping
}];
```

and a method to create those new documents

```
/**
 * Generate user Id, range 1-16777215 (1-FFFFFF, in Hex)
 * @private
 * @return {number}         - random generated user id
 */
UserManager.prototype._generateUserId = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215) + 1;
};

/**
 * Create a user with desired "login" and "mail"
 * @access public
 * @param {string}  login   - user login name
 * @param {string}  mail    - user mail address
 */
UserManager.prototype.createUser = function (login, mail) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    var rec = new this.umodel({ login: login, mail: mail });
    var try_create = (function () {
        rec.id = this._generateUserId();
        rec.save((function (error) {
            if (error)
                if (error.code == 11000) {
                    // E11000: duplicate key error
                    // genre
                    try_create();
                } else
                    d.reject();
            d.resolve(rec.id);
        }).bind(this));
    }).bind(this);
    try_create();
};
```

I managed to make the user's id, username and email address unique by setting it to a unique key, and now I failed to figure out which key is duplicated when I'm getting a duplicated key error.

Comment: Not familiar with the details of Mongoose, but normally it will specify the details of the duplicate key error in the error message. I see there is `error.code`, is there perhaps also `error.message`?

Comment: Yep, you need to parse the error message.

Comment: I'm failing to see how `this.umodel` is even creating a mongoose doc since its not referenced elsewhere in the code. Also why are you duplicating generateUserId with mongoose's uuid. Mongoose is handling that for you so why do it again? Don't recreate the wheel, you'll get further in development if you use what's already provided.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Yes I found that there's a error message here, but I can't figure out how to parse it and if there's possibility of changes to the message format.

Comment: @Ravenous I searched over Google and it said that the ObjectId provided by mongodb isn't unique if I cut it into the length I wanted.